# Upper bound for $2^n- \sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) 2^d$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for an upper bound for $2^n-\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) 2^d$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. I would like an upper bound that holds for large $n$, that is I don't mind if it doesn't hold for a finite number of small values of $n$.    This is the formula for counts of unique periodic binary strings of length $n$ from http://oeis.org/A152061.

It seems an upper bound should be roughly $2^{n/2}$ but this isn't quite right.

Comment: How tight an upper bound do you need? $2^{n/2+1}$ is certainly an upper bound, as is $2^{n/p} + 2^{n/q+1}$ where $p<q$ are the two smallest prime factors of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want an upper bound for the quantity
$$
f(n) = 2^n - \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(\tfrac nd) 2^d = \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\ge2}} -\mu(d) 2^{n/d}.
$$
Note first of all the inequality
$$
\sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\ge C}} -\mu(d) 2^{n/d} \le \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\ge C}} 2^{n/d} \le \sum_{1\le k\le n/C} 2^k < 2^{n/C+1}.
$$
This immediately implies that $f(n) < 2^{n/d}+1$.

We can be more precise: if there is only one prime $p$ dividing $n$, then $f(n) = 2^{n/p}$. Otherwise, let $p<q$ be the two smallest primes dividing $n$. Then the only squarefree divisor of $n$ less than $q$ is $p$, so
$$
f(n) = -\mu(p)2^{n/p} + \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\ge q}} -\mu(d) 2^{n/d} < 2^{n/p} + 2^{n/q+1}.
$$

(Similar arguments give the lower bound $f(n) \ge 2^{n/p}$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$.)